# How do I fix the getAge() to get the age of the oldest student in my code?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public class Student {


public Student(String name, int age, String major, String SSN) {

    }


public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();

        studentList.add(new Student("Alice", 22, "Computer Science", "603-28-5324"));
        studentList.add(new Student("Arthur", 19, "Math","402-23-5463"));
        studentList.add(new Student("Kim", 20, "English","607-34-5463"));
        studentList.add(new Student("Jack", 24, "Science","537-52-6324"));
        studentList.add(new Student("Bob", 27, "Computer Science", "345-23-4354"));
        studentList.add(new Student("Sarah", 21, "Music", "355-67-5352"));
        studentList.add(new Student("Mariah", 19, "Business", "567-45-8774"));
        studentList.add(new Student("Robert", 18, "Art", "732-65-7364"));


        Optional<Student> optional = studentList.stream()
                .max((p1, p2) -> p1.getAge() - p2.getAge());
        if (optional.isPresent()) {
            Student oldest = optional.get();
            System.out.println("The Oldest Student is: " +oldest.getAge() + "(" + oldest.getAge() + ")");

            //getAge() doesn't work. How do I make it so that it will be able to recognize the age in the array and print out the name with the age?

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What `getAge()`?  You never defined a method.

Comment: Hi Jason and welcome to Stack Overflow!  What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  And could you please include some more written English explanation of what you're trying to do and what's failing, and maybe narrow the code down to a [minimum reproducible verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  Thanks!

Comment: I dont know how to create the methods for it to recognize getAge() or getName(). Also just realized i accidentally put getAge() twice in the system print line

Comment: So you want to create a `getAge()` method to return the greatest age in a given array of `Student` objects?

Answer (score 1):

you should create member variables and assign them in the constructor

```
    public class Student {

        String name;
        int age;
        String major;
        String SSN;

        public Student(String name, int age, String major, String SSN) {
            this.name=name;
            this.age=age;
            this.major=major;
            this.SSN=SSN;
        }
        int getAge(){
            return age;
        }
        String getName()
        {
            return name;
        }

//and so on for all your variables
    }
```

Comment: most welcome Jason and please mark the question as solved